# Работа с полями Mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

Подскажите пожалуйста в таком вопросе. Есть поля id и outer_id. Возможно ли реализовать одним запросом чтоб при добавлении новой записи автоинкрементное значение поля id сразу же подставлялось и в поле outer_id ?

Comment: Если это понадобилось - возможно надо пересмотреть структуру БД. Налицо дублирование информации. Может стоит оставлять поле NULL, например

Answer (score 1):

Одним запросом врятли, но в вашем случае подойдет функция **last_insert_id()**

```
update table MYTABLE set
outer_id = id
where id = last_insert_id()
```

Comment: а если между insert и update проскочит еще один insert?

Comment: @plesser, не проскочит, функция возвращает значение именно для текущей сессии.